# Dvorak International Dead Keys in Windows?

Tags: windows, dvorak

I need umlauts with International Dvorak. Is this possible? (I googled I found out that one could use a hack to edit the layouts but seems like I am re-inventing the wheel)

Is it better to use some terminal emulation that would fix the issue or how can I get a proper kbd -layout? I would like to reuse *ix -based solutions, can I emulate X somehow and replace the W -settings with my default debian -settings?)

Answer (score 4):

[Steven Ehrbar](http://personal.jargon-file.org/) maintains a collection of [alternate keyboards for Microsoft Windows](http://keyboards.jargon-file.org/).  In the "General Purpose US Layouts" section you will find two Dvorak International layouts, one with raw dead keys and one where they're activated with AltGr+key combinations.

Comment: This worked for me on Windows 10, but I had to reboot, and I had to add and remove the "United States" language in order to get rid of an extra entry in the keyboard layout switchers.

Comment: On a 64-bit installation, run the file named `_amd64.exe`, and on a 32-bit installation, run the file name `_i386.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I created a project to make my keyboard work on Windows.
It's Dvorak International with dead keys.

https://github.com/edpichler/Apple-Dvorak-on-Windows

Answer (score 0):

The best deadkeys dvorak may is here: http://arjenvankol.com/dvorak.php
Take "http://arjenvankol.com/dvorak/kbdvo-ie.zip" in the bottom on the page
Then unzip, execute "setup.exe" maybe restart your computer (don't remember) and add on your prefered language the "United States-Dvorak international - Custom" layout.